# How can I understand -O3's optimizations?

Tags: c, gcc, optimization

I currently have two functions **A** and **B**.

When compiled without any flags, **A** is faster than **B**.

But when compiled with `-O1` or `-O3`, **B** is much faster than **A**.

I want to port the function to other languages, so it seems like **A** is a better choice.

But it would be great if I could understand how `-O3` managed to speed up function **B**. Are there any good ways of at least getting a slight understanding of the kind of optimizations done by `-O3`?

Comment: It would be great if you edited your question and included the functions you're talking about, and preferably exact compiler version, so people can see it for themselves and possibly provide a detailed explanation on what compiler is exactly doing in each case.

As it is now, the answer is: depends.

Comment: Start with https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.2.0/gcc/Optimize-Options.html (or the appropriate manual for your version of gcc)

Comment: @Sahsahae I have not included the functions, since I was hoping for a more general answer. Since including code can often have solutions specific to the code. i.e unrolling loops, using bitwise, etc, etc. Rather I was hoping for a way to deduce or understand -O3's optimizations.

Comment: Look at the disassembly, for example with https://godbolt.org/ you can get a full understanding of exactly what happened that way.

Comment: Which optimizations are included in any particular optimization level depends on the exact compiler.  It varies even between different versions of the same compiler.  We have no way at all to answer the question without knowing either the functions or the compiler.  But *you* can certainly refer to your compiler's documentation.  Chances are good that it specifies which optimizations are performed at each level.

Comment: Evaluating the function implementations would probably be better for us, though, because even without discerning the specific optimizations that are making the difference in your case, we can speak in general terms to which approach is more likely to be handled well or optimized well.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I am using GCC 9.1.0. I didn't want to include the function since there would be answers regarding the implementation. e.g unrolling loops, bitwise, etc, etc. Instead I was wondering if there was any way of "interpreting" or "understanding" the optimizations done by -O3.

Comment: "I want to port the function to other languages, so it seems like A is a better choice" Why would it be so? Do you assume that other languages are inherently incapable of optimisations?

Comment: @n.m. No, but other languages have very different optimizations. Therefore, it will quite likely have a different effect compared to -O3. I would assume function that becomes slower without specific optimizations to be slower in other languages, compared to a function that is fast without specific optimizations.

Comment: Compilation without optimisations enabled **is not designed to produce fast object code**. Evaluating something at a task it was not meant to do well is a meaningless waste of time.

Comment: @n.m. I am merely saying, **often**, a function that runs fast without optimization flags, runs faster in different languages than a function which runs faster only when -O3 is enabled. While some functions may be written with -O3 in mind, this is not easily noticeable, such evaluation is usually necessary.

Comment: `-fdump-tree-optimized`

Answer (score 3):

`-O3` does the same as `-O2`, and also:

- Inline parts of functions.
- Perform function cloning to make interprocedural constant propagation stronger.
- Perform loop interchange outside of graphite. This can improve cache performance on loop nest and allow further loop optimizations, like vectorization, to take place. For example, the loop:

```c
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
  for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
    for (int k = 0; k < N; k++)
      c[i][j] = c[i][j] + a[i][k]*b[k][j];
```

is transformed to

```c
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
  for (int k = 0; k < N; k++)
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
      c[i][j] = c[i][j] + a[i][k]*b[k][j];
```

- Apply unroll and jam transformations on feasible loops. In a loop nest this unrolls the outer loop by some factor and fuses the resulting multiple inner loops.
- Peels loops for which there is enough information that they do not roll much. It also turns on complete loop peeling (i.e. complete removal of loops with small constant number of iterations).
- Perform predictive commoning optimization, i.e., reusing computations (especially memory loads and stores) performed in previous iterations of loops.
- Split paths leading to loop backedges. This can improve dead code elimination and common subexpression elimination.
- Improve cache performance on big loop bodies and allow further loop optimizations, like parallelization or vectorization, to take place.
- Move branches with loop invariant conditions out of the loop, with duplicates of the loop on both branches (modified according to result of the condition).
- If a loop iterates over an array with a variable stride, create another version of the loop that assumes the stride is always one. For example:

```c
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
  x[i * stride] = …;
```

becomes:

```c
if (stride == 1)
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    x[i] = …;
else
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    x[i * stride] = …;
```

---

For example, the following code:

```c
unsigned long apply(unsigned long (*f)(unsigned long, unsigned long), unsigned long a, unsigned long b, unsigned long c) {
    for (unsigned long i = 0; i < b; i++)
        c = f(c, a);
    return c;
}

unsigned long inc(unsigned long a, unsigned long b) { return a + 1; }
unsigned long add(unsigned long a, unsigned long b) { return apply(inc, 0, b, a); }
```

Optimizes the add function to:

**Intel Syntax**

```rb
add:
  lea rax, [rsi+rdi]
  ret
```

**AT&T**:

```rb
add:
  leaq (%rsi,%rdi), %rax
  ret
```

Without `-O3` output is:

**Intel Syntax**

```rb
add:
  push rbp
  mov rbp, rsp
  sub rsp, 16
  mov QWORD PTR [rbp-8], rdi
  mov QWORD PTR [rbp-16], rsi
  mov rdx, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
  mov rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-16]
  mov rcx, rdx
  mov rdx, rax
  mov esi, 0
  mov edi, OFFSET FLAT:inc
  call apply
  leave
  ret
```

**AT&T**:

```rb
add:
  pushq %rbp
  movq %rsp, %rbp
  subq $16, %rsp
  movq %rdi, -8(%rbp)
  movq %rsi, -16(%rbp)
  movq -8(%rbp), %rdx
  movq -16(%rbp), %rax
  movq %rdx, %rcx
  movq %rax, %rdx
  movl $0, %esi
  movl $inc, %edi
  call apply
  leave
  ret
```

You can compare the output assembler for functions **A** and **B** using `-S` flag and `-masm=intel`.

*This answer is based on [GCC documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html), you can learn more from it.*

Comment: Can you provide the assembly output in AT&T syntax, too? I find Intel syntax confusing.

Comment: For me, intel syntax is more readable, but I can add AT&T output.

Answer (score 0):

The question being

> Are there any good ways of at least getting a slight understanding of the kind of optimizations done by -O3?

, and the intention apparently being that the question be answered in a general sense that does not take the actual code into consideration, the best answer I see is to recommend reading the [documentation for your compiler](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.1.0/gcc/), especially the [documentation on optimizations](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.1.0/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Optimize-Options).

Although not every optimization GCC performs has a corresponding option flag, most do.  The docs specify which optimizations are performed at each level in terms of those flags, and they also specify what each individual flag means.  Some of the terminology used in those explanations may be unfamiliar, but you should be able to glean at least "a slight understanding".  Do start reading at the very top of the optimization docs.

Comment: Strange, gcc doesn't seem to produce the same assembly even when all flags are enabled.

https://godbolt.org/z/9z9PnJ

https://godbolt.org/z/mg9YuC

But this may be due to different configurations of GCC. I also tried fetching all the enabled optimizer flags with grep:
`gcc -Q --help=optimizers | grep enabled | sed 's/\[enabled\]//g' | tr -d '\n'`, though I may have made mistakes in the command. Yet -O3 still produced different assembly. Strange, but thanks nonetheless.

Comment: @SomeDinosaur, do you mean GCC produces different output when you turn on all the individual flags than it does when you turn on the corresponding numbered optimization-level flag?  As I said (based on the docs), "not every optimization GCC performs has a corresponding option flag [but] most do".

Comment: Any chance you know a compiler flag to stop GCC from changing naive memory copies to `memcpy` with `-O3`? It causes infinite recursion and therefore a segfault.

Comment: @JL2210 `-fno-tree-loop-distribution`, or probably a few others among `-ffreestanding`, `-fno-builtin-memcpy`, etc (no promise that they all work). But really, you are supposed to open a new question (or find one that already answers it), not ask in comments.

Comment: @MarcGlisse https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57539509/how-do-i-stop-gcc-from-optimizing-this-byte-for-byte-copy-into-a-memcpy-call

Comment: Oops, `-fno-tree-loop-distribution` was supposed to be `-fno-tree-loop-distribute-patterns` (I saw "distrib" and copy-pasted too fast)