# How do I stop GCC from optimizing this byte-for-byte copy into a memcpy call?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-optimization

I have this code for **`memcpy`** as part of my implementation of the standard C library which copies memory from `src` to `dest` one byte at a time:

```
void *memcpy(void *restrict dest, const void *restrict src, size_t len)
{
    char *dp = (char *restrict)dest;
    const char *sp = (const char *restrict)src;

    while( len-- )
    {
        *dp++ = *sp++;
    }

    return dest;
}
```

With `gcc -O2`, the code generated is reasonable:

```
memcpy:
.LFB0:
        movq    %rdi, %rax
        testq   %rdx, %rdx
        je      .L2
        xorl    %ecx, %ecx
.L3:
        movzbl  (%rsi,%rcx), %r8d
        movb    %r8b, (%rax,%rcx)
        addq    $1, %rcx
        cmpq    %rdx, %rcx
        jne     .L3
.L2:
        ret
.LFE0:
```

However, at `gcc -O3`, GCC optimizes this naive byte-for-byte copy into a `memcpy` call:

```
memcpy:
.LFB0:
        testq   %rdx, %rdx
        je      .L7
        subq    $8, %rsp
        call    memcpy
        addq    $8, %rsp
        ret
.L7:
        movq    %rdi, %rax
        ret
.LFE0:
```

This won't work (`memcpy` unconditionally calls itself), and it causes a segfault.

I've tried passing `-fno-builtin-memcpy` and `-fno-loop-optimizations`, and the same thing occurs.

I'm using GCC version 8.3.0:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-cros-linux-gnu/8.3.0/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-cros-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr/local --libdir=/usr/local/lib64 --build=x86_64-cros-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-cros-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-cros-linux-gnu --enable-checking=release --disable-multilib --enable-threads=posix --disable-bootstrap --disable-werror --disable-libmpx --enable-static --enable-shared --program-suffix=-8.3.0 --with-arch-64=x86-64
Thread model: posix
gcc version 8.3.0 (GCC)
```

How do I disable the optimization that causes the copy to be transformed into a `memcpy` call?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One thing that seems to be sufficient here: instead of using [`-fno-builtin-memcpy`](https://godbolt.org/z/rZkOIF) use [`-fno-builtin`](https://godbolt.org/z/-pcTgE) for compiling the translation unit of `memcpy` alone!

An alternative would be to pass `-fno-tree-loop-distribute-patterns`; though this might be brittle as it forbids the compiler from reorganizing the loop code first *and then* replacing part of them with calls to `mem*` functions.

Or, since you cannot rely anything in the C library, perhaps using `-ffreestanding` could be in order.

Answer (score 6):

> This won't work (memcpy unconditionally calls itself), and it causes a segfault.

[Redefining `memcpy` is undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50741722/redefining-function-from-standard-library).

> How do I disable the optimization that causes the copy to be transformed into a memcpy call (preferably while still compiling with -O3)?

Don't. The best approach is fixing your code instead:

- In most cases, you should use another name.
- In the rare case you are really implementing a C library (as discussed in the comments), and you really want to reimplement `memcpy`, then you should be using compiler-specific options to achieve that. For GCC, see [`-fno-builtin*` and `-ffreestanding`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html), as well as [`-nodefaultlibs` and `-nostdlib`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html).

Comment: @JL2210 `This is sub-optimal for obvious reasons` suppose it compiles to `__builtin_memcpy` or something similar then your implementation is **far more sub-optimal** for obvious reasons. Modern libraries make use of SIMD and maybe even DMA if available so they'll be much faster than your byte-by-byte copy

Comment: I don't get why people downvote this answer. Both of its points (1. that the builtin `memcpy()` can be expected to be faster, and 2. that redefining `memcpy()` is UB) are perfectly valid and useful. The only place where you want to redefine `memcpy()` is when you are implementing the standard C library, which is the only reason why compilers have to allow switching off the optimization.

Comment: @JohanBoulé How should I present the matter better? I understand that the compiler is faster in all cases (this code is just fallback since I'm preparing faster versions).

Comment: It would be nice if this answer at least attempted how to fix the problem, because, currently, it provides no useful information (other than telling me to fix my code or rename the function). Would it be possible to present a solution (other than "don't do this") to help me get out of undefined behavior-land?

Comment: @JL2210 If I now understand your question, the function you're presenting to us should not be called "memcpy", because what you're interested in is to prevent ordinary loop-copies from being rewritten by the compiler to a memcpy call. But since you named it "memcpy", it's somewhat clear that your secret intent is *also* to replace memcpy with your own, which brings new sorts of questions, that Acorn started to address.

Comment: @JL2210 If you provide an asm memcpy implementation rather than a C-based one, do you then you get rid of the problem where the compiler ends up calling memcpy from memcpy itself ?

Comment: @JohanBoulé Yes, but it's only for one architecture. This issue still affects the other two. If you're really that interested, then here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/226285/string-routines

Comment: @JL2210 For architectures on which you don't have your own optimised code (i.e. asm code), it may make sense to leave the original builtin memcpy alone. Also, I don't think the compiler will call your own version unless you're being explicit about it. And how do you deal with ODR, does it even apply to compiler builtins?

Comment: @AndrewHenle Well, if the OP is legitimately implementing `memcpy()`, they should tell the compiler to disable the entire standard C library...

Comment: @AndrewHenle "*The "you have to fix your code instead" comment in the answer is inappropriate.*" It wouldn't say it was inappropriate, because OP was relying on UB anyway ;) While I didn't notice the function was called `memcpy`, the function body was correct, so I assumed the problem was in the caller. Since OP was complaining about optimizations and didn't mention being implementing the C standard library, it made sense. I have updated the answer to match the edited question better.

Comment: *Redefining* is not the same as *implementing*. Implementing `memcpy` is not rare either for embedded systems; the `-nostdlib` documentation states: *The compiler may generate calls to `memcmp`, `memset`, `memcpy` and `memmove`. These entries are usually resolved by entries in libc. These entry points should be supplied through some other mechanism when this option is specified.*

Comment: @Rodney No, the C standard reserves the identifier. It does not matter whether it is a definition or a redefinition or whether you include the header or not.